# Varnish removes $HTTP_HOST

Tags: nginx, varnish

I have an issue with varnish, wich removes HTTP_HOST variable. My setup is nginx ->(1 from 5 server with:) varnish -> local nginx -> php5-fpm. I'm running several sites, but without `Host` it just display default site.

**/etc/varnish/default.vcl**

```
# This is a basic VCL configuration file for varnish.  See the vcl(7)
# man page for details on VCL syntax and semantics.
# 
# Default backend definition.  Set this to point to your content
# server.
# 
backend default {
    .host = "127.0.0.1";
    .port = "81";
}
# 
# Below is a commented-out copy of the default VCL logic.  If you
# redefine any of these subroutines, the built-in logic will be
# appended to your code.
sub vcl_recv {
#        set req.http.x-host = req.http.host;
#        set req.http.x-url = req.url;
#        set req.http.host = regsub(req.http.host, "^www\.", "");
#   set req.http.host = bereq.url;
    if (req.url ~ "\.(css|js|png|gif|jp(e)?g)") {
        unset req.http.cookie;
    }
    if (req.url ~ "\.(mp4|mp3|avi)") {
        return (pass);
    }
    if (req.restarts == 0) {
    if (req.http.x-forwarded-for) {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For =
        req.http.X-Forwarded-For + ", " + client.ip;
    } else {
        set req.http.X-Forwarded-For = client.ip;
    }
     }
     if (req.request != "GET" &&
       req.request != "HEAD" &&
       req.request != "PUT" &&
       req.request != "POST" &&
       req.request != "TRACE" &&
       req.request != "OPTIONS" &&
       req.request != "DELETE") {
         /* Non-RFC2616 or CONNECT which is weird. */
         return (pipe);
     }
     if (req.request != "GET" && req.request != "HEAD") {
         /* We only deal with GET and HEAD by default */
         return (pass);
     }
     if (req.http.Authorization || req.http.Cookie) {
         /* Not cacheable by default */
         return (pass);
     }
     return (lookup);
 }

# sub vcl_pipe {
#     # Note that only the first request to the backend will have
#     # X-Forwarded-For set.  If you use X-Forwarded-For and want to
#     # have it set for all requests, make sure to have:
#     # set bereq.http.connection = "close";
#     # here.  It is not set by default as it might break some broken web
#     # applications, like IIS with NTLM authentication.
#     return (pipe);
# }
# 
sub vcl_pass {
      set bereq.http.host = req.http.host;
      return (pass);
}
# 
sub vcl_hash {
     hash_data(req.url);
     if (req.http.host) {
         hash_data(req.http.host);
     } else {
         #hash_data(server.ip);
     error 475 "F";
     }
     return (hash);
}
# 
# sub vcl_hit {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_miss {
#     return (fetch);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fetch {
#     if (beresp.ttl <= 0s ||
#         beresp.http.Set-Cookie ||
#         beresp.http.Vary == "*") {
#       /*
#        * Mark as "Hit-For-Pass" for the next 2 minutes
#        */
#       set beresp.ttl = 120 s;
#       return (hit_for_pass);
#     }
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_deliver {
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_error {
#     set obj.http.Content-Type = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
#     set obj.http.Retry-After = "5";
#     synthetic {"
# <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
# <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
#  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
# <html>
#   <head>
#     <title>"} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</title>
#   </head>
#   <body>
#     <h1>Error "} + obj.status + " " + obj.response + {"</h1>
#     <p>"} + obj.response + {"</p>
#     <h3>Guru Meditation:</h3>
#     <p>XID: "} + req.xid + {"</p>
#     <hr>
#     <p>Varnish cache server</p>
#   </body>
# </html>
# "};
#     return (deliver);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_init {
#   return (ok);
# }
# 
# sub vcl_fini {
#   return (ok);
# }
```

**/etc/default/varnish**

```
# Configuration file for varnish
#
# /etc/init.d/varnish expects the variables $DAEMON_OPTS, $NFILES and $MEMLOCK
# to be set from this shell script fragment.
#
# Note: If systemd is installed, this file is obsolete and ignored.  You will
# need to copy /lib/systemd/system/varnish.service to /etc/systemd/system/ and
# edit that file.

# Should we start varnishd at boot?  Set to "no" to disable.
START=yes

# Maximum number of open files (for ulimit -n)
NFILES=131072

# Maximum locked memory size (for ulimit -l)
# Used for locking the shared memory log in memory.  If you increase log size,
# you need to increase this number as well
MEMLOCK=82000

# Default varnish instance name is the local nodename.  Can be overridden with
# the -n switch, to have more instances on a single server.
# You may need to uncomment this variable for alternatives 1 and 3 below.
# INSTANCE=$(uname -n)

# This file contains 4 alternatives, please use only one.

## Alternative 1, Minimal configuration, no VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# content server on localhost:8080.  Use a 1GB fixed-size cache file.
#
# This example uses the INSTANCE variable above, which you need to uncomment.
#
# DAEMON_OPTS="-a :6081 \
#              -T localhost:6082 \
#        -b localhost:8080 \
#        -u varnish -g varnish \
#            -S /etc/varnish/secret \
#        -s file,/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin,1G"


## Alternative 2, Configuration with VCL
#
# Listen on port 6081, administration on localhost:6082, and forward to
# one content server selected by the vcl file, based on the request.
#
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -t 120 \
             -w 8,36,120 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,2048m"


## Alternative 3, Advanced configuration
#
# This example uses the INSTANCE variable above, which you need to uncomment.
#
# See varnishd(1) for more information.
#
# # Main configuration file. You probably want to change it :)
# VARNISH_VCL_CONF=/etc/varnish/default.vcl
#
# # Default address and port to bind to
# # Blank address means all IPv4 and IPv6 interfaces, otherwise specify
# # a host name, an IPv4 dotted quad, or an IPv6 address in brackets.
# VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS=
# VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT=6081
#
# # Telnet admin interface listen address and port
# VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS=127.0.0.1
# VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=6082
#
# # The minimum number of worker threads to start
# VARNISH_MIN_THREADS=1
#
# # The Maximum number of worker threads to start
# VARNISH_MAX_THREADS=1000
#
# # Idle timeout for worker threads
# VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT=120
#
# # Cache file location
# VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE=/var/lib/varnish/$INSTANCE/varnish_storage.bin
#
# # Cache file size: in bytes, optionally using k / M / G / T suffix,
# # or in percentage of available disk space using the % suffix.
# VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE=1G
#
# # File containing administration secret
# VARNISH_SECRET_FILE=/etc/varnish/secret
# 
# # Backend storage specification
# VARNISH_STORAGE="file,${VARNISH_STORAGE_FILE},${VARNISH_STORAGE_SIZE}"
#
# # Default TTL used when the backend does not specify one
#VARNISH_TTL=120
#
# # DAEMON_OPTS is used by the init script.  If you add or remove options, make
# # sure you update this section, too.
# DAEMON_OPTS="-a ${VARNISH_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_LISTEN_PORT} \
#              -f ${VARNISH_VCL_CONF} \
#              -T ${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_ADDRESS}:${VARNISH_ADMIN_LISTEN_PORT} \
#              -t ${VARNISH_TTL} \
#              -w ${VARNISH_MIN_THREADS},${VARNISH_MAX_THREADS},${VARNISH_THREAD_TIMEOUT} \
#          -S ${VARNISH_SECRET_FILE} \
#              -s ${VARNISH_STORAGE}"
#


## Alternative 4, Do It Yourself
#
# DAEMON_OPTS=""
```

UPD:
Without varnish all works correctly, but slow.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sense.

If you have multiple sites, then you need to define multiple backends, and connect to each one conditionally.

At the moment, your only backend is 127.0.0.1, which is generally going to hit your default site in Nginx.

See this answer about how to do that - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3373251/1463157

Comment: Thanks for answer, I'm done with this yesterday. No, it's unnecessary to define multiple backends. I publish my configs as soon as possible.